# When doing su <user> after connecting as root user, it gets hung up in JSCH

Tags: java, ssh, sudo, jsch, su

I'm trying to execute commands in a particular sequence.

(1) Connect to a remote node
 ssh -i path-to-key root@some-remote-node

(2) su user

While doing the same using JSCH, I'm able to connect to the remote node. But when executing the next command, it gets hung. But the same isn't happening when I doing from terminal.

Code,

```
private void execute(String command, Session session, long sleepTime,
            boolean isCloseSession) throws JSchException, IOException {

        System.out.println("Command \"" + command + "\" executed on HOST : "
                + session.getHost());

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command.trim());
        String str = null;

        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i <= 0) {
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                    str = new String(tmp, 0, i);
                    sb.append(str);
                    channel.disconnect();
                    if (isCloseSession) {
                        closeSession();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getClass()
                            + " occured while calling execute(" + command
                            + ", Session, " + sleepTime + ")");
                }
            }

            exitCode = channel.getExitStatus();
            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        response = sb.toString();
        if (isCloseSession) {
            closeSession();
        }
    }

 public void executeCommand(String command, boolean isCloseSession) {
    executeCommand(command, 0, isCloseSession);
 }

 public void executeCommand(String command, long sleepTime,
        boolean isCloseSession) {

    try {
        session = createSession(basicInfo);
        if (session != null) {
            if(!session.isConnected()) {
               session.connect();
            }
            execute(command, session, sleepTime);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Session is NULL!");
        }
    } catch (JSchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Connection to HOST \"" + basicInfo.getHostName() + "\" failed"
                + ex.getStackTrace());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to execute the command \"" + command
                + "\" on the HOST \"" + this.basicInfo.getHostName()
                + "\" : " + ex.getStackTrace());
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SSHUtil util = new SSHUtil(hostName, userName, keyFile);
    util.executeCommand("ls", false); // For this I'm getting response
    System.out.println(util.getResponse());
    util.executeCommand("su hdfs", false); // For this, its going into while(true) {} and breaking no where.
    System.out.println(util.getResponse());
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the source code that you have for running these remote commands.

Comment: Your execute function looks okay offhand. Could you edit your question to include the code that calls this execute function in order to run these two commands that are giving you trouble? Please include the actual command strings that you're running.

Comment: @Kenster: Updated the code. I'm able to execute multiple commands one after the other (just for an example added ls). But when using sudo, its getting into while(true) { .... } inside execute(...) and not exiting at all.

Comment: Running "su hdfs" is going to start an instance of the hdfs user's shell. I don't know what shell this user has, but if it's something like _bash_, it'll just sit idle until it receives a command to run on its standard input. What are you expecting to happen when you run "su hdfs"?